# Calling functions by passing interface type

Tags: java, interface, overloading

For the code below I am not able to understand how are the calls made to the overload functions
can any one give me a detailed explanation how the overload function call is made when the object is made using Side and Tail reference respectively.

```
interface Side {
    String getSide();
}

class Head implements Side {
    public String getSide() {
        return "Head ";
    }
}

class Tail implements Side {
    public String getSide() {
        return "Tail ";
    }
}

class Coin {
    public static void overload(Head side) {
        System.out.print(side.getSide());
    }

    public static void overload(Tail side) {
        System.out.print(side.getSide());
    }

    public static void overload(Side side) {
        System.out.print("Side ");
    }

    public static void overload(Object side) {
        System.out.print("Object ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Side firstAttempt = new Head();
        Tail secondAttempt = new Tail();
        overload(firstAttempt);
        overload((Object) firstAttempt);
        overload(secondAttempt);
        overload((Side) secondAttempt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debug mode?

Comment: It's really unclear exactly what you're confused about. You're calling `overload` four times - which call is confusing you, and in what way?

Comment: the call overload(firstattempt)is confusing me since Side firstattempt=new Head()

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

1. All java objects descend from Object.
2. You defined the interface Side
3. Head implements Side
4. Tail implements Side.

You have four methods with the same name (overload), but which all have different signatures... one accepts a Head, another a Tail, another a Side, and the last an Object. Since both Head and Tail inherit from Side, the method overload(Side side) will accept either as an argument. Similarly, since both Head and Tail descend from Object, overload(Object obj) will accept either.

In your specific example, firstAttempt is of type Side, so when you invoke overload(firstAttempt), you are using the overload(Side side) method. Your second invocation explicitly casts to Object, so you are using overload(Object obj). Your secondAttempt variable is of type Tail, so overload(secondAttempt) invokes overload(Tail tail). And finally, overload((Side) secondAttempt) explicitly casts to Side, so overload(Side side) is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Digest the concept in small chunks!

Understand this code first

```
interface Side
{
String getSide();
}

class Head implements Side
{
public String getSide()
{
    return "Head ";
}
}

class Tail implements Side
{
public String getSide()
{
    return "Tail ";
}
}
```

it creates an interface and 2 classes implement it. override the functions.
Then your final classs,

```
public class Coin
{
public static void overload(Head side)
{
    System.out.println(side.getSide()+" -> "+side);
}

public static void overload(Tail side)
{
    System.out.println(side.getSide()+" -> "+side);
}

public static void overload(Side side)
{
    System.out.println("Side <- "+side);
}

public static void overload(Object side)
{
    System.out.println("Object <- "+side);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Side a = new Head();
    Side b = new Tail();
    Head c = new Head();
    Tail d = new Tail();
    overload(a);
    overload((Side) a);
    overload((Object) a);
    overload(b);
    overload((Side) b);
    overload((Object) b);
    overload(c);
    overload((Side) c);
    overload((Object) c);
    overload(d);
    overload((Side) d);
    overload((Object) d);
}
```

Simulate a dry-run of the main function line by line on paper
mapping the code to the sample output as follows:

For **Side a = new Head()**,

```
Side <- Head@12d5e310
Side <- Head@12d5e310
Object <- Head@12d5e310
```

For **Side b = new Tail()**,

```
Side <- Tail@182e3919
Side <- Tail@182e3919
Object <- Tail@182e3919
```

For **Head c = new Head()**,

```
Head  -> Head@2a6a4b6
Side <- Head@2a6a4b6
Object <- Head@2a6a4b6
```

For **Tail d = new Tail()**,

```
Tail  -> Tail@a87aa16
Side <- Tail@a87aa16
Object <- Tail@a87aa16
```

Mark that the reference is the same for each object, and so is the @hashcode!